Which AWS EC2 instance is most suitable for hosting a website which involves high frequency message logs coming via websockets that displayed on UI?
Which AWS EC2 instance is most suitable for hosting a website which involves high frequency message logs coming via web-sockets that to be displayed on UI ?
Technology Stack:
FrontEnd - Angular - 16.0.2
BackEnd - Flask (Python)
Database - AWS RDS Posgres

This is something you may try and adjust. That is advantage of using cloud - you may scale up or down as you see fit. You may event test on production scale.  Sorry, but with no metrics or more details I don't think you will get better answer

You'll want an EC2 instance that offers a good balance of performance and cost.
t3.large

vCPUs: 2
Memory: 8 GB
Network Performance: Up to 5 Gbps

It's cost-effective and provides a good mix of CPU, memory, and network performance.
c5.large or c5.xlarge

vCPUs: 2 or 4
Memory: 4 GB or 8 GB
Network Performance: Up to 10 Gbps

For handling higher compute and network-intensive tasks, good for your web-sockets.
For higher performance but also price :)
